# How to plot (visualize) a network representing a trained Neural Network with its weights with Bokeh?

Tags: python, graph, neural-network, bokeh

I have trained a Neural Network on some data with the following Keras ANN set-up:

```
estimator = Sequential()
estimator.add(Dense(units=12, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=12, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=12, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=12, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=12, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=12, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=6, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
```

and would like to have a visualization graph of this network, showing for instance:

- the weights between the inputs and each neurons and between neurons of successive hidden layers
- the activity of each neuron
- ...

I was thinking of using bokeh and network graph but was wondering if it is possible?

Or how to structure `estimator` information for it to be possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is an attempt to provide a solution to ANN regressor visualization (generated with keras) through a Bokeh Network.

Comments and improvements are welcome!

I believe this self supporting example can be beneficial to a lot of Keras and machine learning users.

It outputs the ANN structure, with connections between nodes highlighted with line_width and color given by abs(weights). The HoverTool shows the feature_names in the input nodes and the sum of abs(weights) from the node into the next layer.

Illustration example:
[ANN Network Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcjD5.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import Plot, ColumnDataSource, Range1d, Circle, MultiLine
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis
from bokeh.plotting import from_networkx

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

from bokeh.models import HoverTool, StaticLayoutProvider, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.models import (BoxZoomTool, TapTool, ResetTool, PanTool, WheelZoomTool)

Predictors = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4']
TargetVariables = ['t1', 't2']

data_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=Predictors,
                       data=np.random.rand(5000, len(Predictors)))
# We create a sample data for target values with polynomial functions (without noise)
data_df['t1'] = 0.3*data_df['p1']*data_df['p1']*data_df['p3'] \
    + 0.1*data_df['p4']+0.2*data_df['p2']*data_df['p2']
data_df['t2'] = 0.5*data_df['p1'] + 2*data_df['p2']

X = data_df[Predictors].copy()
y = data_df[TargetVariables].copy()

###########################
# Pre-processing (scaling) Y output data:
minMax = data_df.agg([min, max])
for variable in TargetVariables:
    y[variable] = y[variable]/minMax.loc['max', variable]

###########################
# Training of ARTIFICIAL NEURON NETWORK
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

estimator = Sequential()
estimator.add(Dense(units=5, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
estimator.add(Dense(units=len(TargetVariables), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

estimator.summary()
estimator.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


HISTORY = estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=5, epochs=20, verbose=0)

history_dict = HISTORY.history
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['accuracy']
epochs = range(1, len(loss_values)+1)


###########################
# This is the core of the network creation

output_names = y.columns

ann_weights = estimator.get_weights()

source = []
target = []
weight = []
node_initial_pos = {}
node_size = {}
node_color = {}
node_sum_weights = {}

deltaY_nodes = 0.2
deltaX_nodes = 0.4
default_node_size = 10

# Number of maximum nodes per layer on the whole ANN (for proper positioning)
nmn = max(k.shape[0] for k in ann_weights)

# Inputs layer nodes with its targets
for i in range(0, ann_weights[0].shape[0]):
    node_initial_pos[Predictors[i]] = (0, i*deltaY_nodes)
    node_size[Predictors[i]] = default_node_size
    node_color[Predictors[i]] = Viridis[10][0]
    node_sum_weights[Predictors[i]] = np.sum(np.abs(ann_weights[0][i]))
    for j in range(0, ann_weights[0].shape[1]):
        source.append(Predictors[i])
        target.append(str(1)+'_'+str(j))
        weight.append(ann_weights[0][i][j])

layer_number = 0
# Hidden layer nodes with its targets, up to the (n-1) hidder layer
for k in range(2, len(ann_weights)-2, 2):
    layer_number += 1
    for i in range(0, ann_weights[k].shape[0]):
        y_offset = 0.5*(nmn-ann_weights[k].shape[0])*deltaY_nodes  # To center the graph
        node_initial_pos[str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i)] = (layer_number*deltaX_nodes, y_offset+i*deltaY_nodes)
        node_size[str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i)] = default_node_size
        node_color[str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i)] = Viridis[10][9]
        node_sum_weights[str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i)] = np.sum(np.abs(ann_weights[k][i]))
        for j in range(0, ann_weights[k].shape[1]):
            source.append(str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i))
            target.append(str(layer_number+1)+'_'+str(j))
            weight.append(ann_weights[k][i][j])

# Last hidden layer nodes with its output targets
layer_number += 1
for i in range(0, ann_weights[len(ann_weights)-2].shape[0]):
    y_offset = 0.5*(nmn-ann_weights[len(ann_weights)-2].shape[0])*deltaY_nodes  # To center the graph
    node_initial_pos[str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i)] = (layer_number*deltaX_nodes, y_offset+i*deltaY_nodes)
    node_size[str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i)] = default_node_size
    node_color[str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i)] = Viridis[10][9]
    node_sum_weights[str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i)] = np.sum(np.abs(ann_weights[len(ann_weights)-2][i]))
    for j in range(0, ann_weights[len(ann_weights)-2].shape[1]):
        source.append(str(layer_number)+'_'+str(i))
        target.append(output_names[j])
        weight.append(ann_weights[len(ann_weights)-2][i][j])
# Output layer nodes
        y_offset = 0.5*(nmn-ann_weights[len(ann_weights)-2].shape[1])*deltaY_nodes  # To center the graph
        node_initial_pos[output_names[j]] = ((layer_number+1)*deltaX_nodes, y_offset+j*deltaY_nodes)
        node_size[output_names[j]] = default_node_size
        node_color[output_names[j]] = Viridis[10][4]
        node_sum_weights[output_names[j]] = 0.  # we provide no value to this indicator on the output nodes


# Calculate center of network graph (for convenient visualization)
min_x = min(node_initial_pos[k][0] for k in node_initial_pos)
max_x = max(node_initial_pos[k][0] for k in node_initial_pos)
min_y = min(node_initial_pos[k][1] for k in node_initial_pos)
max_y = max(node_initial_pos[k][1] for k in node_initial_pos)
delta_x = max_x-min_x
delta_y = max_y-min_y


df = pd.DataFrame([source, target, weight, np.abs(weight)])
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ['source', 'target', 'weight', 'abs_weight']
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', ['weight'])

nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_color, 'node_color')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_size, 'node_size')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_initial_pos, 'node_initial_pos')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_sum_weights, 'node_sum_weights')

# source with node color, size and initial pos
node_source = ColumnDataSource(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v for k, v in G.nodes(data=True)}, orient='index'))

margin = 0.2
plot = Plot(plot_width=1200, plot_height=800,
            x_range=Range1d(min_x-margin*delta_x, max_x+margin*delta_x),
            y_range=Range1d(min_y-margin*delta_y, max_y+margin*delta_y))

node_hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[("Node name", "@index"), ("Sum of weights", "@node_sum_weights")])
plot.add_tools(node_hover_tool, BoxZoomTool(), ResetTool(), TapTool(), PanTool(), WheelZoomTool())


graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout)
graph_renderer.layout_provider = StaticLayoutProvider(graph_layout=node_initial_pos)

mapper = LinearColorMapper(
    palette='Magma256',
    low=df["weight"].min(),
    high=df["weight"].max()
)

graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source = node_source
graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(fill_color='node_color', size='node_size', line_color='black')
graph_renderer.node_renderer.hover_glyph = Circle(fill_color='node_color', size='node_size', line_color='black')

graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="#CCCCCC", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=2)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[2], line_width=5)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.hover_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[1], line_width=5)

# style
weight_map = dict(zip(zip(source, target), np.abs(weight)))
weight_map.update(zip(zip(target, source), np.abs(weight)))
data = graph_renderer.edge_renderer.data_source.data
data["line_width"] = [weight_map[edge] * 10 for edge in zip(data["start"], data["end"])]
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph.line_width = {'field': 'line_width'}
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph.line_color = {'field': 'weight', 'transform': mapper}

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, label_standoff=12, location=(0, 0), title='Weight')
plot.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')

plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)
output_file('test.html')

show(plot)
```